# Fragments inheritance with newInstance pattern

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, inheritance, fragment

Which is the correct way to make fragments inheritance with newInstance pattern?

For example, if we have a fragment MyFragment that inherits from another fragment SuperFragment which has the newInstance pattern --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28855715/5125212

```
public class SuperFragment extends Fragment{
    public static SuperFragment newInstance(int var1, boolean var2){
        SuperFragment fragment = new SuperFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("my_var1", var1);
        b.putBoolean("my_var2", var2);
        fragment.setArguements(b);
        return fragment
    }
// All other methods
}
```

This gets an error on "super":

```
public class MyFragment extends SuperFragment{
    public static MyFragment newInstance(int var1, boolean var2){
        return super.newInstance(int var1, var2);
    }
// All other methods
}
```

And this gets an error on constructor as we should avoid non-default constructors:

```
public class MyFragment extends SuperFragment{
    public MyFragment(int var1, boolean var2){
        newInstance(var1, var2);
    } 
// All other methods
}
```

And I found this to don't have any error but I don't like it because it semms to get recursively:

```
public class MyFragment extends SuperFragment{
    public static SuperFragment newInstance(int var1, boolean var2){
        return newInstance(var1,var2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find it!

Super fragment:

```
public class SuperFragment extends Fragment{
    public static Bundle setArgs(int var1, boolean var2){
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("my_var1", var1);
        b.putBoolean("my_var2", var2);
        return b;
    }
// All methods you want in the super fragment, so they will be in the 
// inherit fragment too
}
```

Inherit fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends SuperFragment{
    public static MyFragment newInstance(int var1, boolean var2){
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(setArgs(var1,var2));
        return fragment;
    }
// All other methods that you only want them on the inherit (this)     
// fragment
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't even compile because you're trying to return a SuperFragment instead of a MyFragment...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create the overloaded constructor. You pass your data to `newInstanace(var1, var2)` and then you do like this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int var1, int var2)
{
  MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment(); // default constructor by android system
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putInt("my_var1", var1);
  b.putInt("my_var2", var2);

fragment.setArguements(b);

return fragment
}
```

and then in `onCreateView`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        int var1 = arguments.getInt("my_var1", 0);
```

**UPDATE**

Inheritance with newInstance pattern can't be done as static methods can't be overriden. Morever, if you dont have the default constructor, it will be a compile time error to overload default constructor

Comment: Thanks Mustansar Saeed, but I am telling about INHERITANCE of fragments with newInstance pattern.

Comment: inheritance with newInstance pattern can not be done in my opinion as `static` methods `can't be overriden`

Comment: I am not saying anything about override methods... Check the question again, I edit it. Maybe now is easy to understand. Thankss